# HTTPS not returning images from public folder while HTTP does

Tags: https, playframework-2.0

My app works perfectly fine with HTTP, when I moved to HTTPS I am not able to render images. Basically i have following folder structure :

```
-public
----images
--------12243456.jpg
```

I am requesting this image from Javascript by setting HTML img tag

```
<img.src= "<path/to/image>
```

And my request returns with response 404. When I switch to HTTP the same code works.

This is the standard line in my conf file for the static files

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

CSS and JS files are being rendered fine in HTTPS, somehow images are the ones creating problem.

Here is a sample request

```
Request URL:https://hay.com:9443/assets/images/1378237450056.jpg?1378237450057
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PLAY_SESSION="0a28e06a3342d31a45af7182fc4598c202d11890-email=guillaume%40sample.com"
Host:localhost:9443
Referer:https://hay.com:9443/launchCamera/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Could you try asking this on the mailing list?

Comment: I found solution to this. It's something with the Asset Controller of Play. It does not return dynamic assets added while the application is running. So I had to write a handler separately to handle the images and got it to work.Thanks for the help michiel